# JavaFX Button onAction property does not fire when Button pressed on touchscreen

Tags: java, javafx, touch

I'm learning JavaFX and working on a JavaFX application that will turn my laptop's touchscreen into a mini-piano.  My prototype has a bunch of Buttons in place of piano keys, with each button mapped to a different Midi note.  Clicking on a button with the mouse successfully triggers the button's onAction property and plays the associated note.  Poking the button with my finger doesn't.  The program clearly knows where my finger is because when I poke a button with my finger the button changes color, just as it does when I move the mouse pointer into it.  I know that the problem is with JavaFX rather than with Java more generally or with my touchscreen because I wrote an essentially identical prototype in Swing where poking the screen succesfully plays a note.  (I would gladly have stuck to Swing, too, if only Swing had any kind of multi-touch support.  I want to play chords.)  Is there something about JavaFX that I'm missing, such as a touchscreen event handler, or is something deeply wrong here?

For the record, I'm using OpenJDK 11.0.7 and OpenJFX 11.0.2 with a Xubuntu laptop.  Here's the relevant bits of code.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    stage.setTitle("Midi Test");
    buttons = new Button[NOTE_VALUE.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < NOTE_VALUE.length; i++) {
        buttons[i] = new Button(NOTE_NAME[i]);
        buttons[i].setPrefSize(KEY_WIDTH,KEY_HEIGHT);
        buttons[i].setOnAction(this);
    }
    // Layout omitted for brevity
    stage.show();

}

public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

    // Identifies which button was pressed and plays the corresponding note

    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        if (event.getSource().equals(buttons[i])) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index != -1) {
        channels[0].allNotesOff();
        channels[0].noteOn(NOTE_VALUE[index],93);
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems strange, and I don't have the environment to test this. Is the issue that the action event is not getting fired at all, or is it that the event source is not correctly identified? (It's probably better to register a different handler with each button anyway, instead of having a single handler that scans through all the buttons to find a match; but in the second scenario refactoring like this would fix the issue.)

Comment: You have `buttons[i].setOnAction(this);`. Your class is not set up to do anything given this code. At least it does not appear to be.

Comment: @Sedrick It's an old-style way (c. 1998) of handling events, where you make the UI class implement the appropriate event handler(s), and put the logic in the event handler method for figuring out what actually happened. (It's basically a hangover from the days before inner classes.) I agree that people don't typically write code like that any more, but it should work anyway.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @James_D. I didn't test the code . Sorry!

Comment: The action event doesn't fire when I touch the screen, which is odd given that mouse clicks do cause the action event to fire and every other program I use on this machine, including those I wrote myself that use Swing, treats touch events as mouse clicks.  I didn't use an inner class for the event handler in this project because an inner class wouldn't have the scope to see channels[0].  The inner-class event handler would have to call MidiSystem.getSynthesizer().getChannels() every time someone pressed a button, while the current system only has to do it once.

Comment: @John Inside the `for` loop in `start()`, you can do `var noteValue = NOTE_VALUE[i];` and then `buttons[i].setOnAction(e -> {  channels[0].allNotesOff(); channels[0].noteOn(noteValue,93); });`. (Replace `var` with the actual type if you prefer.) Lambdas (and anonymous classes) can access instance variables and effectively-final variables. But my question was are you *certain* the action event handler isn't fired (which seems more likely), and it's not just that `event.getSource()` is not returning one of the buttons? There's no way to determine that from the code you posted.

Comment: If you just create a very simple JavaFX application with a single button, with an action event handler, does it work if you use the touch screen to press the button?

Comment: @James_D I modified the program to produce an error message and stop execution if it can't identify the event source.  That never happens, so I'm reasonably certain that touch input isn't firing the action event.  I'll try a simpler program when I get the chance.  Thanks for the tips about Lambdas.

Comment: You could simply put a `System.out.println(event.getSource())` as the first line of `handle(...)`, of course. Just seems strange that if the button is detecting a mouse press, it's not firing an action event.

Comment: The other troubleshooting I'd suggest is to register `mouseEntered`, `mousePressed`, and perhaps other listeners with the button, just to see what is and isn't getting fired.

Comment: @James_D I wrote a simple, one-button program and experimented with various event handlers.  Touching the button with my finger triggers a MOUSE_ENTERED event.  Lifting my finger triggers a MOUSE_EXITED event.  None of the touch events I tested (TOUCH_PRESSED, TOUCH_RELEASED, etc.) triggered at all.  Neither did MOUSE_PRESSED, MOUSE_RELEASED, or MOUSE_CLICKED.

Answer (score 0):

After adopting @James_D's diagnostic suggestions (thanks, James) and doing some additional research, it looks like the problem is due to a known (but obscure) bug deep in the guts of OpenJFX 11.  See the discussion [here](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/329) for details.  There appear to be some workarounds, but the most straightforward solution would seem to be to try a more recent version of OpenJFX.

Comment: It doesn't look like the issue is resolved, though, at the time of writing. [This comment](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/329#issuecomment-459433106) in the thread you linked suggests a JVM command-line parameter `-Djdk.gtk.version=2`. Anyway: good luck.

Comment: @James_D Thanks.  I looked into the command-line workaround you mentioned, and it's unfortunately only a partial solution.  With that parameter, pressing the touchscreen triggers MOUSE_PRESSED, MOUSE_RELEASED, and MOUSE_CLICKED, but still doesn't trigger any touch events.  That's an improvement, but still not the multi-touch support I was hoping for.  Looks like this project is going on the back burner for a while.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not convinced actions and buttons are what you need here anyway. What you really need is a mouse pressed event on a second node of some kind before the mouse released event on the first node (so you can track pressed and released events independently for each node). That way you can start and stop notes playing independently of each other. But I'm not sure if that's supported with that workaround (again, don't have an environment to test).